# Adding a line of text

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, scintilla

Im looking through the Scintilla documentation but i cant find anything. I want to add a single line of text to a a paticular line on a Scintilla text editor. I would also like to add a line of text on an empty line. This is invoked by a button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The Scintilla docs can be very useful for understanding the low-level stuff, but to begin with, you'd probably be better off with the docs for the [high-level api](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/annotated.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the class QsciScintilla as your widget.

In this case you can use the method

```
editor = QsciScintilla()
editor.insertAt(text, line, index)
```

Insert the text text in the line line at the position index.